# How to fill an array in MATLAB within the range by a math formula correctly?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, math

Yeah, kinda easy stuff, but can't find an exact solution or my brain is a bit dummy today. I'm trying to fix it nearly the whole day.

The task is
[image: my task]

My code:

```
clear; clc;
t = 0:40*pi;
f = zeros(size(t));
x = zeros(size(t));
y = zeros(size(t));
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
s = 5; 
for k = 0:40*pi
    f(k+1) = exp(cos(k)) - 2*cos(4*k) - (sin(k/12))^5;
    x(k+1) = x0 + s*f*sin(k);
    y(k+1) = y0 + s*f*cos(k);
end
surface(x, y, f, 'r');
```

The error is: `Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.`

My thoughts on "why?":
Because of `k+1` in `f`,`x`,`y` and without `-1` at `k`. But even with that it shows the same error. I don't know how to deal with that properly.

Just need to calculate these formulas at each time step and fill the arrays with data. Pretty super easy task, but something is missing.
Thanks!

**Update**:

Haven't seen the f in formulas for x and y, fixed it to be `f(k+1)`. Now arrays are filled correctly.

```
    x(k+1) = x0 + s*f(k+1)*sin(k);
    y(k+1) = y0 + s*f(k+1)*cos(k);
```

Now the problem is creating a surface plot out of it.

```
>>surface(x, y, f); Warning: Error creating or updating Surface.
  Error in value of property ZData. Array is wrong shape or size.
```

Comment: FIXED!
Haven't seen the f in formulas for x and y, fixed it to be f(k+1).
Now arrays are filled correctly.

Comment: BUT! 
Now the problem with creating a surface plot out of it. 

>>surface(x, y, f);
Warning: Error creating or updating Surface
 Error in value of property  ZData
 Array is wrong shape or size

Comment: use `plot3(x, y, f, '.r');`